# mathematica, calculate average per hour

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a big amount of weatherdata. its listed by date and time. there is a value every 10 minutes. start from 600 till 1400

I would like to calculate the Average of every hour for the two values.

nr ,date1, time1, val ,nr date, time, val2

thanks

```
  {11238, 20120530, 1300, 11290, 20120530, 1300, 141}, {11238, \
20120530, 1310, 11290, 20120530, 1310, 223}, {11238, 20120530, 1320, \
11290, 20120530, 1320, 201}, {11238, 20120530, 1330, 11290, 20120530, \
1330, 275}, {11238, 20120530, 1340, 11290, 20120530, 1340, 371}, \
{11238, 20120530, 1350, 11290, 20120530, 1350, 275}, {11238, \
20120530, 1400, 11290, 20120530, 1400, 238}, {11238, 20120531, 600, \
11290, 20120531, 600, 342}, {11238, 20120531, 610, 11290, 20120531, \
610, 238}, {11238, 20120531, 620, 11290, 20120531, 620, 438}, {11238, \
20120531, 630, 11290, 20120531, 630, 483}, {11238, 20120531, 640, \
11290, 20120531, 640, 498}, {11238, 20120531, 650, 11290, 20120531, \
650, 535}, {11238, 20120531, 700, 11290, 20120531, 700, 527}, {11238, \
20120531, 710, 11290, 20120531, 710, 461}, {11238, 20120531, 720, \
11290, 20120531, 720, 572}, {11238, 20120531, 730, 11290, 20120531, \
730, 624},
```

Comment: data={{11238...141},{11238...,223},...}; getvals[{v1_, v2_}] := {v1[[4]] - v2[[4]], v1[[7]] - v2[[7]]}; avgvals[v_] := Mean[vals]; pairs = Map[getvals, Partition[data, 2, 1]]; avgs = N[Map[Mean, Partition[pairs, 6]]] gives me the mean of each of the first two hours for each val {{0., -16.1667}, {0., -49.5}}. Study the details of this until you can figure out how this works and be able to use it to solve problems in the future.

Comment: Have a look at `GatherBy`.  Also as a suggestion you might want to look into converting your numeric values into mathematica date objects ( see `DateObject` ). That will make a bunch of useful tools available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your data format as given: `{nr, date1, time1, val, nr date, time, val2}`, the following code outputs the date & hour and averages of val and val2.

```
data = {
   {11238, 20120530, 1300, 11290, 20120530, 1300, 141},
   {11238, 20120530, 1310, 11290, 20120530, 1310, 223},
   {11238, 20120530, 1320, 11290, 20120530, 1320, 201},
   {11238, 20120530, 1330, 11290, 20120530, 1330, 275},
   {11238, 20120530, 1340, 11290, 20120530, 1340, 371},
   {11238, 20120530, 1350, 11290, 20120530, 1350, 275},
   {11238, 20120530, 1400, 11290, 20120530, 1400, 238},
   {11238, 20120531, 600, 11290, 20120531, 600, 342},
   {11238, 20120531, 610, 11290, 20120531, 610, 238},
   {11238, 20120531, 620, 11290, 20120531, 620, 438},
   {11238, 20120531, 630, 11290, 20120531, 630, 483},
   {11238, 20120531, 640, 11290, 20120531, 640, 498},
   {11238, 20120531, 650, 11290, 20120531, 650, 535},
   {11238, 20120531, 700, 11290, 20120531, 700, 527},
   {11238, 20120531, 710, 11290, 20120531, 710, 461},
   {11238, 20120531, 720, 11290, 20120531, 720, 572},
   {11238, 20120531, 730, 11290, 20120531, 730, 624}};

(* format the time data to hourly timestamps *)
times = (
     date = ToString[#2]; 
     hour = StringPadLeft[ToString@Floor[#3/100], 2, "0"];
     {date, hour}) & @@@ data;

(* join the timestamps to the data *)
datawithtimes = MapThread[Prepend, {data, times}];

(* gather the data by the timestamps *)
gathered = GatherBy[datawithtimes, First];

(* pick out the data and average *)
{StringJoin[Insert[First@#1, " ", 2], "00"],
     N@Mean[#5], N@Mean[#8]} & @@ Transpose[#] & /@ gathered
```

> ```
> {{20120530 1300, 11290., 247.667},
>  {20120530 1400, 11290., 238.},
>  {20120531 0600, 11290., 422.333},
>  {20120531 0700, 11290., 546.}}
> ```